# Can I work with Visual Studio Offline?

Tags: visual-studio, offline, visual-studio-community

I lost internet for a while (Im just back). When I try to create a new project to test a few thing while waiting. Get a message can't download Nuget package when trying to create a controller.

So can I setup Visual Studio to have a local version, so I can keep working even if lose internet?

I try to google but only have instruction for installing VS offline. Not about working offline.

Comment: Welp, I had this problem even after installing on offline. Check the guide here https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/visualstudio-docs/blob/main/docs/install/create-an-offline-installation-of-visual-studio.md

and the problem-resolution guide here https://pupuweb.com/solved-visual-studio-community-license-expired-evaluation-period-ended/

Answer (score 0):

Yes!, after you install Visual Studio, you can use it even if you have no connection, obviously the functions that require internet can not be used.

If Scaffolding is a internet function, you cannot use it if you not have internet

Comment: Well that is the point. If I cant create a controller by scalfonding I cant use it.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Visual Studio without internet

Creating Project works fine

And Building tool also works fine

There are some codes or files that need internet in order to work, But don't worry

*(Note that I'm using VS 2022)*